# Woocommerce product restriction by attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a trying to make a pice of code that i can put in my functions.php
It needs to check what the selected attributes of the first product in the cart is. After that it needs to block all other product with an OTHER attributes than the selected one in the cart.

In my case:
Product 1 has attribute: color, attribute: height.
Product 2 has attribute: color, attribute: height.
etc..

IF 
product 1 is added in the cart with color black.
THEN
all the other products in the shop can only be added with color black.

I have several try's with editing existing code but none of them work :S

```
    function check_if_cart_has_product( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {  

    if(!empty(WC()->cart->get_cart()) && $valid){
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            if( $product_id == $_product->id ) {
                wc_add_notice( 'The product is already in cart', 'error' );
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_if_cart_has_product', 10, 3 );
```

This will allow only one product in cart and blocks the rest, it only needs the check for the right conditons...

I try to combine it with this pice of code without success

```
function get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $item_id ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $item_id );
    $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
    $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true );  // this will give all variation detail in one line
    // $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, false);  // this will give all variation detail one by one
    return $variation_detail; // $variation_detail will return string containing variation detail which can be used to print on website
    // return $variation_data; // $variation_data will return only the data which can be used to store variation data
}
```